# CSS - image ignores max-height in fluid container - jsFiddle inside

Tags: image, css

Exmaple:
http://jsfiddle.net/vjqjv/7/

I have an image inside of a container (see #slider-section in the jsFiddle) which has a fluid height and a fixed max-height.

I have set max-height and max-width on my image to 100% (see #slider-img).

The Problem: When the browser window gets beyond a certain width, the image ignores the max-width and max-height setting and just gets larger then its container.

You can see it if you open the jsFiddle and expand the width of the browser.

The goal is to get the image to never exceed the width and height of its container and keep its aspect ratio.

This could be achieved by giving the container (#slider-section) a fixed height. However this is not a possible solution for me since it needs to be a fluid height.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your fiddle seems broken, I'm getting a 403 error when loading the img tag.

Comment: It worked when i wrote it :(

I changed the image hoster:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjqjv/7/

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with either FF or Chrome. They both behave differently, but the img is always within it's container for me.

Comment: it happens when you increase the width but keep the height fairly small. And yes, the overflow of the image is hidden, but its acutally larger then the container

Comment: Heres a screenshot of what i mean:
Working: http://i.imgur.com/fUjwS.png
Image too large:http://i.imgur.com/irrfc.png

Comment: @user1259801 Tried different combinations of `width, height, %/px, position, float` attributes, but this seems to me like an unsolvable problem. That overflow:hidden is probably not the right way. I guess it requires at least one absolute height to work. (Btw, in Firefox Ctrl+Alt+i is easiest for tests.)

Comment: is it possible to solve with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?  http://jsfiddle.net/vjqjv/10/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="slider-section" class="clearfix">
        <div id="slider-img-container">
            <img id="slider-img" src="http://s1.directupload.net/images/120715/jy5nvhce.png" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="slider-div-remaining" class="slider-div">
            <div>
                <h1>empfang</h1>
                <p>Der Empfangsbereich - weil es für den ersten Eindruck keine zweite Chance gibt!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    border: 0 none;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
html, body 
{
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
}
#slider-section
{
    height: 58.3658%;
}
#slider-img-container
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#slider-img
{
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
}

.clearfix::after {
clear: both;
}
.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
content: "";
display: table;
font-size: 0;
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
​
```

Comment: No, the image needs to be fluid width/height and the container cant be fixed height